# Put Image background to visual studio code in ubuntu

Tags: image, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, background

I installed Visual Studio Code (VSCode) on Ubuntu and tried to set an image as the background, but I couldn't do it using any extension. I tried using the 'background-cover' extension v2.3.3, but it simply doesn't work. I also tried the Doki Theme, which changed the theme upon installation, but it didn't set the image background. After installing Doki Theme, if I try to change the theme, it doesn't allow me and instead directs me to a tab to change permissions with this command: 'sudo chown -R $(whoami) /snap/code/133/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench'. Although this command made some changes, I still have the same problem. I also tried using the command 'sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench', but it says it can't find the folder. I don't think I need to use this command.

i tried sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, i reinstalled doki and change permissions on the image file but doesent work

Comment: why in the H** do you want a background image in your editor, many cases you lose all contrast between the colored text and the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed vscode with snap, there is an issue with Linux-Snap-VSCode.

Applications installed using snap are inherently read-only, to solve this try to install VSCode using [deb](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) or [rpm](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).